# Mix in some text with DateAdd

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for your time, I have this formula below which at the moment displays last month name in a cell:

```
Worksheets("Calculations").Range("D2").Value = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "MMMM"
```

So now it's displaying January in cell D2, what I want is for this to display "Report for January"

As a bonus it would be awesome to display this: "Report for January 2021" but if that adds too many complications than I'll be happy just to mix in "Report for" part in.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
format(dateadd("m",-1,now),"""Report for ""MMMM YYYY")
```

Note the "escaping" of the included quotation marks

Of course, you could also use:

```
"Report for " & format(dateadd("m",-1,now),"MMMM YYYY")
```